# Output Impedance with Series Diode

Tags: network

Can someone explain how do i find the output impedance of the given cct?
The typical method involves attaching a voltage source at the output and shorting all independent voltage source (and open cct of independent current sources) and then measuring the current and thus obtaining the output impedance.
How do i do that for this cct? (and therefore explain the output of the simulation)

[image]

Comment: The small-signal output resistance of this circuit depends on the diode dynamic resistance \$r_d\$ determined at the operating point. Once you have \$r_d\$, the output resistance is \$r_d || R_1\$.

Comment: I got it, thanks. (Didnt realize that Rin= 1K +Rd and Rout= Rd||1K)

Comment: Glad if I could shed some light on this circuit!

Comment: @VerbalKint That looks a lot like an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the output impedance of this circuit by determining the dynamic resistance of the diode \$r_d\$. Look at the data-sheet and determine the dynamic drop around a given operating point. Looks like \$I_f\$ is around 11.4 mA in your circuit (\$\frac{12-0.6}{1000}\$).

[image]

The output resistance at the given bias current is then \$R_{out}=r_d||R_1\$